# Installing ArcGIS Web ADF?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, installation, arcgis-web-adf

I'm trying to install ArcGIS WEB ADF. How can I install this tool?

My project contains `ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls, Version=10.0.0.0` but I cannot run project because I must install ArcGIS WEB ADF.

I found the following page, but I don't understand how can get administrative privileges.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#//008900000010000000.htm

Comment: I googled 'arcgis 10.0 web adf install' and found http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/install_guide/arcgis_server_net_install_guide/index.html#//008900000010000000.htm

Comment: yes i found this page but how i get administrative privileges for download this adf ?

Comment: Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to improve it with clarifications such as this, please?  There is no guarantee that potential answerers will read comments.